# Will ordering of multiple groupArray aggregations be consistent with each other?

Tags: clickhouse

The [docs](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/grouparray/) for the `groupArray` function warns that

> Values can be added to the array in any (indeterminate) order.... In
> some cases, you can still rely on the order of execution. This applies
> to cases when SELECT comes from a subquery that uses ORDER BY.

Does this just mean that the array will not neccessarily be in the order specified in the `ORDER BY`? Can I depend on the order of multiple `groupArray`s in the same query being consistent with *each other*?

For instance given the records:

```
{commonField:"common", fieldA: "1a", fieldB:"1b"}
{commonField:"common", fieldA: "2a", fieldB:"2b"}
{commonField:"common", fieldA: "3a", fieldB:"3b"}
```

Can I depend on the query

```sql
SELECT commonField, groupArray(fieldA), groupArray(fieldB) FROM myTable GROUP BY commonField
```

to return

```
{
  commonField:"common",
  groupedA:[
    "2a", "3a", "1a"
  ],
  groupedB:[
    "2b", "3b", "1b"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> multiple groupArrays in the same query being consistent with each other?

Yes. They will be consistent.

Anyway you can use Tuple & single groupArray. And Tuple is usefull if you have NULLs, because ALL aggregate functions skip Nulls.

```
create table test (K Int64, A Nullable(String), B Nullable(String)) Engine=Memory;
insert into test values(1, '1A','1B')(2, '2A', Null);


select groupArray(A), groupArray(B) from test;
┌─groupArray(A)─┬─groupArray(B)─┐
│ ['1A','2A']   │ ['1B']        │
└───────────────┴───────────────┘

---- Tuple (A,B) one groupArray ----

select groupArray( (A,B) ) from test;
┌─groupArray(tuple(A, B))───┐
│ [('1A','1B'),('2A',NULL)] │
└───────────────────────────┘

select (groupArray( (A,B) ) as ga).1 _A, ga.2 _B from test;
┌─_A──────────┬─_B──────────┐
│ ['1A','2A'] │ ['1B',NULL] │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘

---- One more Tuple trick - Tuple(Null) is not Null ----

select groupArray(tuple(A)).1 _A , groupArray(tuple(B)).1 _B from test;
┌─_A──────────┬─_B──────────┐
│ ['1A','2A'] │ ['1B',NULL] │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘

---- One more Tuple trick tuple(*)

select groupArray( tuple(*) ) from test;
┌─groupArray(tuple(K, A, B))────┐
│ [(1,'1A','1B'),(2,'2A',NULL)] │
└───────────────────────────────┘
```